# Datagrid - apply changes but CellTemplate with current data

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, binding, datagrid

I'm trying to make a DataGrid where the user can edit data and apply oder cancel changes afterwards.
Moreover one `DataGridCell` has a `TemplateSelector` to help the user to enter just the valid data. `(DateTime, Boolean,...)`
My Model has some properties. For my problem there are two relevant:
`Model.Type` and `Model.Value`

In CodeBehind my properties have the type:

```
enum Type;
string Value;
```

When the user edits the `Value` the TemplateSelector should get the right DataTemplate depending on `Type`

My XAML looks like this:

```
    <DataGrid x:Name="datagrid"                       
                      ItemsSource="{Binding Variables}"                       
                      HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"                       
                      VerticalAlignment="Stretch"                       
                      AutoGenerateColumns="False"                                  
                      IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True">
                <DataGrid.Columns>
                    <DataGridComboBoxColumn Header="{StaticResource VariablesType}" 
                                            ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource VariableTypes}, Mode=OneWay}" 
                                            SelectedItemBinding="{Binding Type}" 
                                            Width="80"/>
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="{StaticResource VariablesValue}" Width="2*">
                        <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplateSelector>
                            <TemplateSelector:TemplateSelector_Variables>
                                <!--Definitin of Templates,..-->
                            </TemplateSelector:TemplateSelector_Variables>
                        </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplateSelector>
                        <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Value}"/>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn>
                </DataGrid.Columns>
     </DataGrid>
```

Let's get to the TemplateSelector:

```
    public override DataTemplate SelectTemplate(object item, DependencyObject container)
    {
        if (item == null)
            return base.SelectTemplate(item, container);
        RaVariableType VariablenType = ((RaVariable)item).Type;
        //SelectingLogic
        //Here I would need the CURRENT type but it gives me the type of my Model
    }
```

I have alread had a solution:
If I use:

```
SelectedItemBinding="{Binding Type, UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged"}"
```

It works BUT I would like to handle an `OK` or `Cancel` of the User and this code changes my Model.

**Another question:**
How do you handle such a decition. (How do you update the Model - code of the command)

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Are you using MVVM pattern. You need to handle it in View Model just bind button to the SelectedItem of the DataGrid and use it whenever the Command is invoked. Ideal way to do this kind of stuff is using commands (Basically MVVM pattern) you can create a command in your Data Object(ViewModel) and call Button.Command , So that there wont be any code behind like Button click.

Example is shown here

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel>
                        <Button 
                      Command="{Binding   Path=DataContext.OKCommand,       
RelativeSource= {RelativeSource FindAncestor,
AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}}">
                        </Button>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
```

View model code

```
 RelayCommand _okCommand;
public ICommand okCommand
{
    get
    {
        if (_ok == null)
        {
            _ok= new RelayCommand(param => this.Show());
        }
        return _ok;
    }
}

private void Show()
{
    if (Parent != null)
    {
        // Handle ok logic Here
    }
}
```

Are you using any patterns like Ninject, Unity etc and entity framework for handling your db layer code ?. Your viewmodel will contain properties and the column names of your grid should come from model property. Once the property value changes you need to write save logic probably using EF or linq to sql db code. Save logic will be handled by seperate class and if the user clicks a button your view model should call the interface method and do the save. Instance of your class which handles save logic will be supplied by Unity or Ninject (depending on your implementation). Your dependencies will be injected into your view models, and your view models would expose properties that are bound to by the view.

For passing the selected item from grid to model
Create a Property in the ViewModel for saving the selected User: public User SelectedUser { get; set; }

Bind SelectedItem of the datagrid view to this Property: SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedUser}"

There are a few way to select items in the DataGrid. It just depends which one works best for your situation

First and most basic is SelectedIndex this will just select the Row at that index in the DataGrid

```
<DataGrid SelectedIndex="{Binding SelectedIndex}" />

private int _selectedIndex;
public int SelectedIndex
{
get { return _selectedIndex; }
set { _selectedIndex = value; NotifyPropertyChanged("SelectedIndex"); }
}
```

SelectedIndex = 2;

SelectedItem will select the row that matches the row you set

```
<DataGrid SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedRow}" />

private DataRow _selectedRow;
public DataRow SelectedRow
{
get { return _selectedRow; }
set { _selectedRow = value; NotifyPropertyChanged("SelectedRow");}
}

SelectedRow = items.First(x => x.whatever == something);
```

The most common one is SelectedValue with SelectedValuePath set, in this case you set the column you want to select with and then to can select the row by setting the corresponding value

```
<DataGrid SelectedValuePath="Size Quantity" SelectedValue="{Binding SelectionValue}" 

private string _selectedValue
public string SelectionValue 
  {
get { return _selectedValue; }
set { _selectedValue = value; NotifyPropertyChanged("SelectionValue"); }
}

SelectionValue = "Blue";
```

XAML Example

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication21.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="202" Width="232" Name="UI">

<Grid DataContext="{Binding ElementName=UI}">
    <DataGrid SelectedValuePath="Size Quantity"        
              SelectedValue="{Binding SelectionValue}" 
              SelectedIndex="{Binding SelectedIndex}"
              ItemsSource="{Binding SizeQuantityTable}"
              AutoGenerateColumns="True" 
              Margin="0,0,0,41" />
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Height="37" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" >
        <Button Content="SelectedIndex" Height="26"  Width="107" Click="Button_Click_1"/>
        <Button Content="SelectedValue" Height="26"  Width="107" Click="Button_Click_2"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: Thank you for your fast reply but I think you totally misunderstood my question.
I know how to handle the OK-Command and so on - the think I don't know the code  how to update my Model from the existing datagrid data.

And the main question - how to select the right datatemplate depending on the current item editing.

Comment: Thank you for you detailed answer!
I don't have any patterns for a database because I just get the data once via a XML-file into an ObservableCollection<Model>.
Then my user is able to edit this ObservableCollection<Model> and when he clicks to the save button, I want to update my ObservableCollection with the Collection of my DataGrid.

I would do it the following way:
BindingMode - Explicit
Get every Cell - get the BindingExpression - Update Source.
Is that ok or ugly?

Comment: It's ok but if you change your db logic by adding more columns to your database table you need to change your wpf code again. So if you do it with patterns you have advantage of separation of concerns and you need not worry about changing your presentation code every time your db change.

Comment: Are ther patterns for xml?

Comment: Data can come from anywhere and dependency inject will handle the separation of concerns. If your data is xml you can handle save logic using Linq to XML. You can get plenty of tutorial online about linqtoxml

Comment: Thank you!
An the styling-problem you would solve with selected index?

Comment: You can get the current selected item using selected index and choose the template accordingly.

Comment: Thanks. Please do not forget to mark or up vote the answer provided by stack overflow members. If the answer is not useful or incorrect you can also down vote or unmark the answer.

Comment: Just help me one more time: How do I pass the current row to my TemplateSelector? It's not a DependencyObject and I cannot access the DataGrid?